# find database data

Tags: database, webmatrix-2

I using webmatrix to build a website.
I use the database which webmatrix sapply, where can I see the database?
In the project folder I see only the source files, but not the database.

Answer (score 1):

Click the Databases button in the left pane to see the data. Go to App_Data form the Files workspace to see the sdf file.